# Integral of odd angle of sin/cos

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Couldn't manage evaluating the integral:
$\int_{i=1}^\infty cos(\theta ^{5})d\theta$

What I could figure out is that this integral doesn't converges absolutely because the function isn't bounded, but couldn't prove anything about convergence.
Tried to use the substitution u=$\theta ^{3}$ but it gives nothing.
Also tried to go with Taylor series but no Idea how to do that.
Thanks!

Comment: Try a change of variable to get rid of the power inside the sine.

Comment: Have you studied Gamma functions yet? Because you could just apply Euler's theorem to express sin as exponential, get rid of the $i$ by substitution of $\theta = i x^{1/5}$, and finally obtain $A\int_{1}^{\infty} x^{t-1} e^{-x} dx = A \Gamma(t, 1)$ the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: unfortunately we didn't learn this subject of Gamma functions

Comment: unfortunately, the representation with the Gamma function is the most "basic" one you can get for this kind of integrals.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out the solution.
because I needed only to check the convergence and haven't had to find the value of the integral, I can go this way:

substitute $u = y ^{5}$, then after arithmetic operations I will get to:
$\frac{cos(x)}{x^{4/5}}$
then by dirichlet's theorem it converges but doesn't converge absolutely.